# Update the top row of each group - Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update, updates

The need is to update only the top row of each group of a table from the data of other table.

I need to update table A with details from table B

```
Table A
---------
ID Name   Date      PCNO
 1  abc  1/1/12      123
 2  def  1/1/12      234 
 3  fgh  1/2/12      222
 4   asd 1/2/12      234

TABLE B
-----------
ID Name   Date       PCNO
1   adsf  1/1/12      4343
2   sdf   1/2/12      9347
```

For each top record of table A grouped by "Date" and ordered by PCNO desc, I would like to update the values from table B.

Do i use rank for this purpose.?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results you expect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rank or dense-rank (or even row-number) to get identify the 'top' row, though you may need t consider what to do if ties are possible in your real data:

```
select a.id, a.name, a.date_col, a.pcno,
  dense_rank() over (partition by date_col order by pcno desc) as rnk
from table_a a;

        ID NAME DATE_COL         PCNO        RNK
---------- ---- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2 def  2012-01-01        234          1
         1 abc  2012-01-01        123          2
         4 asd  2012-01-02        234          1
         3 fgh  2012-01-02        222          2
```

And you can join to table B to get the new values for the top-ranked:

```
select a.id, a.name, a.date_col, a.pcno,
  dense_rank() over (partition by a.date_col order by a.pcno desc) as rnk,
  case when dense_rank() over (partition by a.date_col order by a.pcno desc) = 1
       then b.name else a.name end as new_name,
  case when dense_rank() over (partition by a.date_col order by a.pcno desc) = 1
       then b.pcno else a.pcno end as new_pcno
from table_a a
join table_b b on b.date_col = a.date_col;

        ID NAME DATE_COL         PCNO        RNK NEW_   NEW_PCNO
---------- ---- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---- ----------
         2 def  2012-01-01        234          1 adsf       4343
         1 abc  2012-01-01        123          2 abc         123
         4 asd  2012-01-02        234          1 sdf        9347
         3 fgh  2012-01-02        222          2 fgh         222
```

and you can then use that in a merge statement:

```
merge into table_a target
using (
  select a.id, a.name, a.date_col, a.pcno,
    dense_rank() over (partition by a.date_col order by a.pcno desc) as rnk,
    case when dense_rank() over (partition by a.date_col order by a.pcno desc) = 1
         then b.name else a.name end as new_name,
    case when dense_rank() over (partition by a.date_col order by a.pcno desc) = 1
         then b.pcno else a.pcno end as new_pcno
  from table_a a
  join table_b b on b.date_col = a.date_col
) source
on (source.id = target.id)
when matched then update
set target.name = source.new_name, target.pcno = source.new_pcno
where source.rnk = 1;
```

or maybe

```
merge into table_a target
using (
  select a.id, a.name, a.date_col, a.pcno,
    case when dense_rank() over (partition by a.date_col order by a.pcno desc) = 1
         then b.name else a.name end as new_name,
    case when dense_rank() over (partition by a.date_col order by a.pcno desc) = 1
         then b.pcno else a.pcno end as new_pcno
  from table_a a
  join table_b b on b.date_col = a.date_col
) source
on (source.id = target.id)
when matched then update
set target.name = source.new_name, target.pcno = source.new_pcno
where target.name != source.new_name or target.pcno != source.new_pcno;
```

either of which reports `2 rows merged`, and then:

```
select * from table_a;

        ID NAME DATE_COL         PCNO
---------- ---- ---------- ----------
         1 abc  2012-01-01        123
         2 adsf 2012-01-01       4343
         3 fgh  2012-01-02        222
         4 sdf  2012-01-02       9347
```

You may need to adjust it if there isn't always going to be a match for a date, though the inner join ought to take care of that.

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a065a6acec41c1612fb8cb0a6be51de9)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am sorry but the requirement is i need to rank after the join.

Comment: @Santosh - I'm not sure what you mean by 'rank after the join'. You haven't shown your expected result in your question, which would have been helpful; but this seems to be what you described. If this isn't right then please add more realistic example data and expected results to your question.

Comment: No worries. Thank you for the help. This is the right question, I got confused. I can delete the comment if you want me to.